# Apple Keyboard A1016 loses Bluetooth after restart on Big Sur

Tags: keyboard, wifi, bluetooth, big-sur

I'm typing this on my old but great A1016 Apple Wireless Keyboard on a 16" MBP running Big Sur with all of the updates installed. No problems except that the keyboard loses bluetooth connection after restart.

I read there were firmware updates for that keyboard but haven't found any. Would (perhaps) be able to install those with my older MBP 17 running High Sierra…

Would not want to exchange that keyboard against any of those new ones, it writes beautifully and so much faster than the aluminum ones. And it is sooo "clicky" ;-)

If anybody has an idea about this, help would be really appreciated.

[image]